# "Chess is art" who was the first one to use this quote?

Tags: history, psychology, quotations

Who was the very first one to ever use the quote "Chess is art"? Like who was the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anybody has made such a claim. "Chess is *an* art" is another matter.

Vaclav Havel (former Czech prime minister) is supposed to have said that when he visited the Carlsbad tournament.

Karpov is supposed to have said "Chess is everything - art, science, and sport."

If anyone should know it would be [Marcel Duchamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcel_Duchamp) the artist who gave up art for chess. Although since he put forward a urinal as a work of art I would hope that he would put chess on a more elevated plane.

Perhaps the most quoted saying about the nature of chess is [Tarrasch's](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Siegbert_Tarrasch)

> Chess, like love, like music, has the power to make men happy

which does it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a quote attributed to Alexander Alekhine:
"To me, chess is not a game; it is art."
http://www.huffingtonpost.com/lubomir-kavalek/chess-art-under-alekhines_b_3195822.html

This is probably a translation from Russian (or maybe French?), so there also exists Brian Towers preferred version: 
"Chess for me is not a game, but an art. Yes, and I take upon myself all those responsibilities which an art imposes on its adherents. – Alexander Alekhine."